# Alternatives to long polling?

Tags: java, ftp, long-polling, ftp-server

I have an application in JAVA which checks from the ftp server, whether a given file is updated or not. If the file is updated, I download the file again.
I am using long polling to check, whether the file has  been modified. So I ping the FTP server every 5 seconds and check whether the modified date of the file is changed or not. If the date is modified, I re-download the file again.
Is there a better way to perform this operation, other than long polling?

Comment: If your only interface to the server is standard FTP, then no, there is no alternative to (long) polling.  FTP servers send files only in response to client requests, and there is no mechanism for notifications.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are two approaches for checking for updates.

The first is the one that you mentioned, and that is polling for changes periodically.

The second solution, is to register a "hook" which will be invoked once a  specific action is occurs. For example, when pushing to a git repository, you can create a hook to automatically start a build of the source code.

In your case, option two is not applicable. There isn't an obvious way to make the FTP server ping you once the files change.